# Eslint config: How to make the case and break of switch in the same indentation?

Tags: javascript

When I use eslint, I need to write switch in this format to pass:

```
switch (value) {
    case "a":
        // do something....
        break;
    case "b":
        // do something....
        break;
}
```

I don't want break to rank behind the case, which will make me very uncomfortable。How to change to the following format to make eslint pass smoothly:

```
switch (value) {
    case "a":
        // do something....
    break;
    case "b":
        // do something....
    break;
}
```

I didn't find other configurations about switch in the eslint document, only switchCase. This is my eslint configuration:

```
"rules": {
        "no-constant-condition": "error",
        "no-delete-var": "error",
        "no-empty": "error",
        "no-empty-character-class": "error",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
        "no-undef": "error",
        "no-var": "off",
        "consistent-this": ["error", "that"],
        "vue/attribute-hyphenation": "off",
        "vue/max-attributes-per-line": ["error", {
            "singleline": 10,
            "multiline": {
                "max": 10,
                "allowFirstLine": true
            }
        }],
        "vue/html-self-closing": "off",
        "vue/html-indent": ["error", 4],
        "vue/order-in-components": "off",
        "vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline": "off",
        "vue/script-indent": ["error", 4, {
            "baseIndent": 1,
            "switchCase": 1,
            "ignores": []
        }],
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "semi-spacing": [0, {
            "after": true,
            "before": false
        }],
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style": [
            "error",
            {
                "multiline": {
                    "delimiter": "semi",
                    "requireLast": true
                },
                "singleline": {
                    "delimiter": "semi",
                    "requireLast": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: "*…after configuring eslint*" - you'll need to show us **how** you configured eslint. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant configuration files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: emmm...my description is wrong, I'm sorry, it should have said "use eslint" is more appropriate. I only used some basic configuration. The only option related to switch is switchCase. I don't see other configuration items about switch in the documentation. I have revised my question, thanks for your suggestion.  @Bergi